# The prefix "crs" for element "crs:course" is not bound

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

Didn't I bind the crs namespace in the opening course tag? The issue appears to actually be the xsi:schemaLocation statement, but I'm not sure what that is. I'm applying namespaces to the student and course elements to address name collision on the firstName and lastName elements.  I would think this would be pretty straightforward.

```
<crs:course courseID="PSAT-080-5"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmins:crs="http://example.com/higheredtestprep/courses/ns"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/higheredtestprep/courses/ns courses.xsd">
   <name>
      <title>PSAT Mathematics Course</title>
      <session>5</session>
   </name>
   <description>
      This is a focused course for students who
      have previously taken the PSAT exam as a sophomore
      but did not receive a desired score on the mathematics 
      portion or students who will be taking the PSAT and 
      wish to strengthen their skills in the mathematics 
      area. Outcomes of the course will be measured using 
      the original PSAT mathematics score compared to a
      course post-test, or a course pre-test compared to the
      subsequent PSAT mathematics score.
   </description>
   <instructor>
      <firstName>Rachel</firstName>
      <lastName>Polygoni</lastName>
   </instructor>
   <stu:students xmlns:stu="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/higheredtestprep/courses/ns studentsvb.xsd">
       <student stuID="I8900-041" courseID="PSAT-080-5">
          <lastName>Garcia</lastName>
          <firstName>Georgianna</firstName>
          <examDate>2017-10-17</examDate>
          <pretest level="M">55</pretest>
          <score>51</score>
       </student>
    
       <student stuID="I7711-121" courseID="PSAT-080-5">
          <lastName>Smith</lastName>
          <firstName>Ryan</firstName>
          <examDate>2017-10-17</examDate>
          <pretest level="L">25</pretest>
       </student>
    
       <student stuID="I7012-891" courseID="PSAT-080-5">
          <lastName>Zheng</lastName>
          <firstName>Paddy</firstName>
          <examDate>2017-10-17</examDate>
          <pretest level="H">65</pretest>
       </student>
    
       <student stuID="I8053-891" courseID="PSAT-080-5">
          <lastName>Steinke</lastName>
          <firstName>Devon</firstName>
          <examDate>2017-10-22</examDate>
          <pretest level="M">51</pretest>
       </student>
    
       <student stuID="I8154-741" courseID="PSAT-080-5">
          <lastName>Browne</lastName>
          <firstName>Brenda</firstName>
          <examDate>2017-10-22</examDate>
          <pretest level="L">30</pretest>
       </student>
    </stu:students>
</crs:course>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a syntax error that can be hard-to-spot with certain fonts...

Change `i` in your namespace prefix definition for `crs`,

```
xmins:crs="http://example.com/higheredtestprep/courses/ns"
  ^
```

to `l`:

```
xmlns:crs="http://example.com/higheredtestprep/courses/ns"
  ^
```